# Unit test in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing

```
class HttpUtils{
    def get(userId: String, organization: String, url: String) = 
    {
        Logger.debug("Request - GET :: " + url)
        val wsClient = AhcWSClient()
        wsClient.url(url).withHttpHeaders("userId"-> userId,"organization"-> organization).get()
        .andThen { case _ => wsClient.close() }
        .andThen { case _ => system.terminate() }
    }
}
```

class MetamodelClient @Inject() (httpUtils: HttpUtils)(implicit defaultExecutionContext: ExecutionContext) {

implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

def getDBDetails(userId: String, organization: String, metamodelUrl: String, model: String) = {
    httpUtils.get(userId, organization, metamodelUrl + "/models/" + model + "/modelsets").map {
      resp =>
        resp.status match {
          case Status.OK => parse(resp.body).extract[List[DatabaseDetails]]
          case _         => handleError(resp.status)
        }
    }
  }
}

Not able to write test case program for getDBDetails Method.Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 2):

You should think about *why* you want to write a test for this code, which will help guide you to *how*.

See e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/top-8-benefits-of-unit-testing

There are a number of problems here that make testing this hard:

1. The method doesn't do anything with the result of "`get()`"
2. There is no way to verify what the correct request is here, without involving the remote system. We hope that the `get` call shown is right, but there is no way to test that it does what you hoped without connecting to your remote API and trying it. That would be out of scope for unit testing.
3. The method has significant side-effects, including shutting down the ActorSystem
4. The method is tightly coupled to the class `AhcWSClient`

I would consider injecting a WS client factory to fix (4).

I would consider refactoring your shutdown process to separate it from application logic, to fix (3).

I would not test this code, because of (1) & (2). There is no way to verify that it is correct with a unit test.

If you did insist on testing this, perhaps because you have an inflexible 100% coverage policy enforced upon you, I would do something more like:

```
class SomethingFetcher(clientFactory: () => AhcWSClient, somethingApiUrl: String) {

  def get(userId: String, organization: String): Something = {
    val wsClient = AhcWSClient()
    wsClient.url(url).withHttpHeaders("userId"-> userId,"organization"-> organization).get()
    .andThen { case _ => wsClient.close() }
  }
}

...

class SomethingFetcherSpec {
  "SomethingFetcher" should "invoke GET on the specified URL" in {
    // arrange
    val mockWsClient = ... // this will be a bit fiddly
    val wsClientFactory = () => mockWsClient 
    val fetcher = SomethingFetcher(wsClientFactory, "http://example.com/something")

    // act
    val ignored = fetcher.get("test uid", "test oid")

    // assert
    verify(mockWsClient).get("http://example.com/something")
  }
}
```